# How can Hashing prevent collision when mapping key-value pairs?

Tags: hash, mapping

If the point of hashing is to prevent collision on key value pairs (map), how can hashing achieve this? If you give a hashing algorithm the name "Jon Smith", wouldn't it give you the same result every time? Thus, what's the difference in just using "John Smith" without hashing the string, as in, if we had two different John Smiths with differing values, how do we know why one we're supposed to pick, since chaining is basically just putting all john smiths in a bucket, and the two john smiths might return different values and we would need to know which one it is.

I've tried googling it but I couldn't find good answers, I would really appreciate some explanation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Collisions don't means that you get a different hash every time, but instead that two different inputs produce the same output. You would also not use a hash as an identifier, but as a way to sign something, or conceal a password with the ability to verify it afterwards.

Comment: I edited my question to illustrate better what I meant

Comment: No, you don’t hash on the key-value pair, you hash on the key alone. If you have one “key” (like “John Smith”) with two values (2 or 5), then it’s not a one to one mapping anymore. You can use the full tuple as a key to hash, so (John Smith, 2) is different from (John Smith, 5), but that’s a different hash and a different data structure (like a list or set of pairs) In general, hashing is an implementation detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you understand the idea of hasing wrong. Normally, it should return the same value every time you use the Hashing-function, in other words, it should be deterministic.

Hashing has other benefits:

- It can be used to calculate an index out of the object, which then can be used for example in hash-sets or hash-maps. A hash-map calculates the hash for the key and then stores the value associated with that key at the position of the hash in an array.
- A big collection of objects can be compared more easily if it contains duplicates
- You can store the hash-values of passwords instead of the password itself. When the user wants to log in, you check if it produces the same hash-value that you initially stored.

There is a collision if two different inputs are mapped to the same hash-value. In other words, the hashing-function is not [injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function). Ideally, there is no hash-value that is produced significantly more often than others, which means the the resulting values are evenly distributed.

Comment: Yeah but that's exactly the problem. If it returns the same value every time you hash a key, say you hash a key string "john smith" with value 5 (key value pair), and another john smith with value 2, then john smith returns the same hash but you never know which one to pick when you try to look them up using the hash, since there are two and  they have different values.

Comment: so you want to store the pair("john smith", 5) and the pair ("john smith", 2) ? In this case you could store it as a set of pairs. Then you would have to hash the pair of both values, which should results in different outputs, as 2 and 5 are different.

Comment: Is this what's happening when you map a key value pair in java? @Morinator

Comment: No, for example in a hash-map, for each key exactly 1 value is assigned, not multiple like 2 and 5. A map is just not what you are looking for. What you want might be HashSet<PersonNumberPair>, where PersonNumberPair has two fields, which contain the information you want to pair up.

Comment: So you can't add John Smith with value x and another John Smith with value y in a hash-map? Then again, what's the point of hashing?

Comment: The idea of the map interface in Java is exactly the same as a function in mathematics, if you want a precise definition.

Comment: oh right, that makes sense. But again, what's the purpose of hashing in that case?

Comment: I already listed the most uses in my initial answer.

Comment: Oh whoops, my bad.  I got distracted by our conversation :P

Comment: Right, so hashing might be useful for when you want to store values in arrays, for which the index must not be a string, but a number. So you end up converting the string to a number by hashing, where it can now be used as an index

Comment: Right. Thats what you do in a HashMap in Java. Except that you wouldn't store the String itself at that spot, but instead the value you want to associate with it.